# Disabling a tkinter button returns nonetype error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
                            edit_bar=Tk()
                            self.entry_bn=Entry(edit_bar)
                            self.entry_bn.grid(row=0,column=1)
                            submit_bn=Button(edit_bar,text="Submit Business Name",command=self.business_name)\
                                       .grid(row=1,column=2)
def business_name(self):
                            self.businessname=self.entry_bn.get()
                            submit_bn["state"]="disabled"
```

Hello,
I am trying to disable the button once the 'business name' has been input and the button clicked. 
I am getting:

```
      submit_bn["state"]="disabled"
'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

as my error. 
Any ideas on why this may not be working would be great. I believe i have used the correct syntax for disabling a button, although there seems to be many alternatives. 
Any help would be great and if you need the whole of my code please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: `submit_bn` *isn't a Tkinter button* - it's indeed `None`, the return value of the `.grid()` method you applied to the actual button.  This is like writing `X = 2 + 3`, and expecting `X` to end up with a value of two.  You have to do the geometry management as a separate statement if you want to keep a reference to the widget.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

edit_bar = tk.Tk()

entry_bn = tk.Entry(edit_bar)
entry_bn.grid(row=0, column=1)

def business_name():
    businessname = entry_bn.get()
    if len(businessname) > 0:
        submit_bn.config(state='disabled')

submit_bn = tk.Button(edit_bar, text="Submit Business Name", command = business_name)
submit_bn.grid(row=1, column=1)

edit_bar.mainloop()
```

When you input a business name, its length should be always be greater than 0, and then disable the button.